# IE7 and IE6 do not pass params in a form_tag in Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, parameters

Strangest bug I've ever come across. Just kidding, but its definately at the top.

If I created a dynamic form like so..

```
= form_tag main_index_path, :method => :post do
  .payment
    = text_field_tag "payments[0][:date_paid]"
    = text_field_tag "payments[0][:amount_paid]"
    %br/
  = link_to 'Add Another Payment', '#', :class => "add_another"

  .actions
    %br/
    = submit_tag 'calculate'
```

And click on `'Add Another Payment'`

A new .payment div will appear like so :

```
.payment
  = text_field_tag "payments[1][:date_paid]"
  = text_field_tag "payments[1][:amount_paid]"
```

Strange as it is *only* in IE6 and IE7, it will pass only the **first** and **last** Payments.

How/Why/What can I do to fix this?

For reference, here is the 'add_another' method :

```
$(".add_another").click(function(){
  if ($(".payment:last").find("input").val() != "") {
    var $newdiv = $(".payment:last").clone(true);
    $newdiv.find('input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('id', $this.attr('id').replace(/_(\d+)_/, function($0, $1) {
            return '_' + (+$1 + 1) + '_';
        }));
        $this.attr('name', $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
            return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
        }));
        $this.val('');
    });
    $newdiv.find('textarea').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.attr('id', $this.attr('id').replace(/_(\d+)_/, function($0, $1) {
          return '_' + (+$1 + 1) + '_';
      }));
      $this.attr('name', $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
          return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
      }));
      $this.css("color","#cccccc");
    });
    $newdiv.insertAfter('.payment:last').hide().slideDown();
  };
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I suggest you simply use the current time (in milliseconds) for the id of your new payments, you'll be sure it's unique.

Comment: You think that's why its failing to pass params? On inspect of params, *only* the first and last come through.

Comment: I don't think it's related, I should have been clearer, was just a tip to spare some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 requires you to clone using OuterHTML

```
      var $this = $(this);
      if (!$.browser.msie || parseInt($.browser.version) > 7) {
        $this.attr('id', $this.attr('id').replace(/_(\d+)_/, function($0, $1) {
            return '_' + (+$1 + 1) + '_';
        }));
        $this.attr('name', $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
            return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
        }));
      } else {
        foob_name = $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
            return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
        });
        foob_id = $this.attr('id', $this.attr('id').replace(/_(\d+)_/, function($0, $1) {
            return '_' + (+$1 + 1) + '_';
        }));

        $this.attr("outerHTML", "<input type='test' name=" + foob_name + " id=" + foob_id + " />");

      };
```

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that you're getting the first and last payments.. Tis a long shot, but being IE..

Is there any way you can check if your insertAfter is working correctly in that your CSS selector .selector:last is **actually**  selecting the **new** last element in your group?

I haven't checked this but what happens if you replace:

```
$newdiv.insertAfter('.payment:last').hide().slideDown();
```

with this:

```
$(".payment").last().after($newdiv).hide().slideDown();
```

Comment: Ah great point. Also I found out a little more information here, but it's right alongside you're answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939433/what-in-this-jquery-code-is-failing-for-ie6-and-ie7 . I tried your answer, and it returned this : `An error as occurred in the script on this page. Line 34 ( that's the line ) Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: Ah ok it should be this `$(".payment:last").after($newdiv).hide().slideDown();` , but no it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Apologies trip, glad you found your answer though ;)